# HeartBleed python test script

Tags: python, security, openssl, heartbleed-bug

I came across [this Python script](https://gist.github.com/takeshixx/10107280) that tests the server for the HeartBleed vulnerability:

Would someone be able to explain the content of the "hello", what is being sent and how was this content constructed?

I am not trying to use this script maliciously. I was asked to test a Tomcat 7.0.2 server for the vulnerability: I verified that tcnative-1.dll does use openssl 1.0.1d, but a few of the standalone test tools that I tried testing the server with report that it is not vulnerable.

Comment: It could be that the server has the heartbeat protocol extension disabled.

Comment: The bug is actually triggered by `hb` or `18 03 02 00 03
01 40 00`. The 0x18 is the `contentType 24` or Heartbeat Message. The 0x4000 at the tail says "My heartbeat message is 0x4000 in size. Please copy 0x4000 bytes back when you respond".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`hello` and `hb` define bytestrings in a more readable fashion.

The `h2bin(x)` function does all the work:

```
def h2bin(x):
    return x.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '').decode('hex')
```

so the string of hex digits has all whitespace removed, then is decoded from hex to bytes:

```
>>> '16 03 02 00 dc'.replace(' ', '')
'16030200dc'
>>> '16 03 02 00 '.replace(' ', '').decode('hex')
'\x16\x03\x02\x00\xdc'
```

It's just a compact way to specify a series of bytes using hexadecimal notation and extra whitespace.

The hex data itself is just a normal [heartbeat protocol message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6520), in raw bytes. The `hello` string contains a [TLS 1.1 record message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346), identified by the first byte (`16` hex, 22 decimal) as a handshake record, sending a `client_hello` (sixth byte is `01`). This is just setting up a TLS session, telling the server what kind of ciphers the client supports. It doesn't really matter what's contained in this, other than that it tells the server the client supports the Heartbeat extension (a `00 0f` byte pair at the end of the message).

It is the *`hb` message* that is interesting one, really:

```
hb = h2bin(''' 
18 03 02 00 03
01 40 00
''')
```

`18` is the heartbeat content type record, `03 02` identifies the TLS 1.1 protocol version. The `00 03` denotes how large the payload of the message is; 3 bytes, or all of the second line.

The 3 bytes of the message itself consists of the heartbeat type (`01`, or 'request'), and the message length (`40 00`, 16384 bytes), followed by **no actual message**. This causes a broken SSL server to send back a heartbeat response containing 16kb of memory; the non-existing 0-length request message is echoed plus the memory to make up the request length.

Comment: "18 is the heartbeat content type record" => What is this content type record then in this case (18), please ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. 18 is the registered type for a heartbeat extension message.

Comment: 16 is for example to say it is a handshake type, what about 18 ?

Comment: 18 is the heartbeat, see the [Heartbeat extension](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6520).

Comment: I read that RFC at least 4 times, nothing like 18 content type record is mentioned.

Comment: @nakkini: 18 hex is 24 decimal. See section 6, *IANA Considerations*.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I found it on RFC 5246 that is related to the ciphersuite (TLS_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 )

Comment: @MartijnPieters Where can I find the info like "18 is the content type record" ? I went through many RFC files and couldn't find it.

Comment: @polurupraveen section 6 in the RFC I linked to above; hex 18 is 24 in decimal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thankyou. Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 6):

[This page](http://www.garage4hackers.com/entry.php?b=2551) explained a lot about that.

```
const unsigned char good_data_2[] = {
    // TLS record
    0x16, // Content Type: Handshake
    0x03, 0x01, // Version: TLS 1.0
    0x00, 0x6c, // Length (use for bounds checking)
        // Handshake
        0x01, // Handshake Type: Client Hello
        0x00, 0x00, 0x68, // Length (use for bounds checking)
        0x03, 0x03, // Version: TLS 1.2
        // Random (32 bytes fixed length)
        0xb6, 0xb2, 0x6a, 0xfb, 0x55, 0x5e, 0x03, 0xd5,
        0x65, 0xa3, 0x6a, 0xf0, 0x5e, 0xa5, 0x43, 0x02,
        0x93, 0xb9, 0x59, 0xa7, 0x54, 0xc3, 0xdd, 0x78,
        0x57, 0x58, 0x34, 0xc5, 0x82, 0xfd, 0x53, 0xd1,
        0x00, // Session ID Length (skip past this much)
        0x00, 0x04, // Cipher Suites Length (skip past this much)
            0x00, 0x01, // NULL-MD5
            0x00, 0xff, // RENEGOTIATION INFO SCSV
        0x01, // Compression Methods Length (skip past this much)
            0x00, // NULL
        0x00, 0x3b, // Extensions Length (use for bounds checking)
            // Extension
            0x00, 0x00, // Extension Type: Server Name (check extension type)
            0x00, 0x0e, // Length (use for bounds checking)
            0x00, 0x0c, // Server Name Indication Length
                0x00, // Server Name Type: host_name (check server name type)
                0x00, 0x09, // Length (length of your data)
                // "localhost" (data your after)
                0x6c, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x74,
            // Extension
            0x00, 0x0d, // Extension Type: Signature Algorithms (check extension type)
            0x00, 0x20, // Length (skip past since this is the wrong extension)
            // Data
            0x00, 0x1e, 0x06, 0x01, 0x06, 0x02, 0x06, 0x03,
            0x05, 0x01, 0x05, 0x02, 0x05, 0x03, 0x04, 0x01,
            0x04, 0x02, 0x04, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02,
            0x03, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x03,
            // Extension
            0x00, 0x0f, // Extension Type: Heart Beat (check extension type)
            0x00, 0x01, // Length (skip past since this is the wrong extension)
            0x01 // Mode: Peer allows to send requests
};
```