# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' Python3

Tags: python

This line works perfectly in python **2.7.6**, but fails in **Python 3.3.5**. How i can decode to `hex` value in Python 3.

```
return x.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '').decode('hex')
```

**Traceback**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Maybe duplicated: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340319/python-3-1-1-string-to-hex)

Comment: The [Heartbleed Python script](https://gist.github.com/takeshixx/10107280) is written for Python 2, not Python 3 :-) You'll need to address more issues other than the payload definition.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I sense that we are going to be getting many similar quetsions very soon...

Comment: @rcomp Note that the script has been ported to Python 3 by the github community: https://gist.github.com/dyatlov/10192468

Answer (score 2):

To convert hexadecimal to a string, use [`binascii.unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify).

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify(x.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', ''))
```

However, you first need to make `x` into `bytes` to make this work, for Python 3. Do this by doing:

```
>>> x = x.encode('ascii', 'strict')
```

And then do the hex-to-string conversion.

Comment: Looking at the [original source](https://gist.github.com/takeshixx/10107280) the point is to produce *bytes* to send over a socket. The decode isn't needed in that case.

Comment: NP, I was just [answering a different question about the same script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033219/heartbleed-python-test-script/23033261#23033261) and recognized the line.

Comment: note: `x.encode('ascii', 'strict')` is not necessary on Python before/after 3.2

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I don't quite understand you, but would what I have done in my edit be preferrable?

Comment: `unhexlify()` doesn't work with `str` objects in Python 3.2. Assuming that `x` contains hexdigits then you could use `x.encode('ascii', 'strict')` to convert `str` object to `bytes`.